# My finite state machine is over prematurely

Tags: java, state-machine

I've been looking at the same problem for two hours now.  I hope some fresh eyes can help me.

this is a stupid lil game of hanoi i'm making.

once my machine enters PLAY it automatically goes to OVER in the next loop no matter what.  I want it to continuously loop PLAY state til the game objective is achieved.  What did I do wrong here?

```
 //program stuff below
enum State {INTRO, BEGIN, PLAY, OVER, END}
static State gamestate;

public static void print(String s){

    System.out.println(s);
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rings = 0;
    gamestate = State.INTRO;
    Towers t = new Towers(1);
    do {
        switch(gamestate){

        case INTRO: System.out.print("Towers of Hanoi: A Children's Game\n by Julio Ollarvia\n\n\n");
                    gamestate = State.BEGIN;

        case BEGIN: System.out.print("How many rings would you risk?: ");

                    try{
                        rings = in.nextInt();
                        t = new Towers(rings);
                        print("\nturn out the lights and light a candle...");
                        gamestate = State.PLAY;

                    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                        System.out.println("/n lets keep it between 0 and 64, bad boy.");

                    }



        case PLAY: print(t.toString());
                   print("this ring is free, grab 1,2, or 3... ");
                   try{
                    int movefrom = in.nextInt();
                    print("to complete your fun, choose 3,2, or 1...");
                    int moveto = in.nextInt();
                    t.move(movefrom,moveto);
                    if (t.peg2.getRingCount() == rings){
                        print("rings: "+rings);
                        print("peg: "+t.peg2.getRingCount());
                        gamestate = State.OVER;
                    }
                   }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                    print("Pegs are numbered between 1 and 3. Please choose just 1,2,3. And don't choose the same one.");

                   }
                   print(gamestate == State.OVER? "over": "still goin'");




        case OVER: print("Better luck next time.\n   wait... no. You won!  "+5*rings+" paraBitCoin has been deposited into your account.\n Please allow"+
                " 28 business days for transaction to complete.");

                gamestate = State.END;
        }

    }while(gamestate != State.END);
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: You don't have any `break` statements in your cases.  Java switch statements default to falling through.

Comment: ah thanks! Ill try it.  be sure  to post a real answer so I can give u credit if it works.

Comment: You can find problems such as these by learning how to use the debugger in your IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you don't have any `break` statements in your cases.

In Java the default for case statements in a switch is to fall through.  That is, after one case is executed, the next will also run:

```
    int a = 1;
    switch (a) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("This gets printed");
        case 2:
            System.out.println("So does this");
    }
```

If you want only the matching case to execute, you need to explicitly break out of the switch statement at the end of the matching case:

```
    int b = 1;
    switch (b) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("This gets printed");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("This doesn't");
    }
```

In your code, no matter what `gamestate` you are in, each case after the matching one will be executed, culminating in case `OVER` which sets the state to `END` and dumps you out of your loop.